# Stripping new lines except for the code that is between code tags

Tags: php, regex

To compress my PHP website i'm removing all the newlines and unneeded whitespaces with the ob_start function. However because i'm using some code (programming language markup), which is newline sensitive, I would like to maintain those newlines and spaces when text is between pre tags.

```
<?php 

  session_start(); 

  function callback($buffer) {

    $search = array(
          '/\>[^\S ]+/s', 
          '/[^\S ]+\</s',  
          '/(\s)+/s',     
          '/(\n)+/s',  
    );

    $replace = array(
          '>',
          '<',
          '\\1',
          ''
    );

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);

    return $buffer;
  }

  ob_start("callback"); 

?>
```

I'm struggling with the regular expression so I would appreciate some help with this one. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `callback` ?

Comment: If you're parsing HTML, use an HTML parser. What are those extra bytes going to add up to anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood You well, You might want to try this..

```
function oneLine($str)
{   // HTML code to a single line
    return((strpos($str,"</pre>")) ? $str:preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$str));
}
```

The code above will wipe all tab/newline/feed charaters and turn those into single blank space, making the whole string a single line. But, if there is `</pre>` ending tag found, nothing will happen.

Conclusion? If Your page content is not echoed in one shot, but Your have $head, $nav, $aside, $article (etc, etc ..) and you output these piece by piece, than `echo(oneLine($nav))` *(and so on) is all it takes.

Even if You don't but You spit all out in one shot eg: `echo(oneLine($request));` and You don't have plethora of preformatted text or just a few pages that do display some code samples, etc.. "sacrificing" those particular pages with `pre` tags for the sake of non-trimmed fashion .. I mean, is it worth bothering .. ?

Answer (score 0):

Might be able to use the skip/fail verbs to accomplish this

Find `(?:<pre>.*?</pre>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s+)`
Replace `" "`

```
 (?:
      <pre> .*? </pre>
      (*SKIP)(*FAIL)
   |  \s+ 
 )
```